# Views: Page by view-group where multiple results are loaded under each group from a relationship

Tags: views

I have a view displaying data as follows:

**Course name 1**

- Course instance a
- Course instance b

**Course name 2**

- Course instance a
- Course instance b
- Course instance c
- Course instance d

**Course name 3**

- Course instance a
- Course instance b
- Course instance c
- Course instance d

The view is grouped by **Course name**, and there's a relationship with the course instance table to bring in the course's course instance.

The pager is set to 10, but the list displays 10 course instances. How can I get it to display 10 Course names, with all of their instances underneath.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.

You can make a view that displays course instances as an unordered list, with a contextual filter that is the parent course nid.

Then create a view of courses, limited to 10, and add a view field to the view, using the first view you made. You can pass in the course nid as the contextual filter, so that field just displays the result of the first view for that particular course.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just had a good think about it and realised that I'm going to want the exposed filters to also apply to the values brought back in each row too. Can you send through the filter values to the child view?

Comment: Not currently (although with some custom code I'm sure you could do it). However, there is a patch relating to this at http://drupal.org/node/966478 (currently comment #5). It is out of date though apparently and need to be re-rolled so it applies to the latest version of the module.

Comment: OK, thanks very much. I'll have a look into this. Cheers.